# How to deallocate resources after fork?

Tags: memory, exec, fork

Say I want to deallocate child's copy of the resources (memory, fds) after fork, but keep running the current binary, i.e. no exec(). Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Hmm.. don't call `exec()`? I know it's a 'duh' answer, but recall that `fork()` creates a copy of the parent process. If you want it to remain that way, then simply don't call `exec()`.

Comment: "I want to child's copy of the resources (memory, fds) after fork" - huh? could you rephrase it? it's a grammatical mess, and because of that, ambiguous.

Comment: Oops. Word "deallocate" was missing. Sorry about that.